# Question about <foreach> task and the failonerror attribute‏

Tags: nant, oracleforms

I have made a build file for the automated compilation of Oracle Forms files. An excerpt of the code is as follows:

```
<target name="build" description="compiles the source code">

... 

  <foreach item="File" property="filename" failonerror="false" >
    <in>
      <items basedir="${source.directory}\${project.type}\Forms">
        <include name="*.fmb" />
      </items>
    </in>
    <do>
      <exec program="${forms.path}" workingdir="${source.directory}\${project.type}\Forms" commandline="module=${filename} userid=${username}/${password}@${database} batch=yes module_type=form compile_all=yes window_state=minimize" />
    </do>
  </foreach>

...

</target>
```

The build file navigates to the directory containing the forms that the user desires fo compile and attempts to compile each form. The failonerror attribute is set to false so that the build file does not exit if a compilation error occurs. Unfortunately, however, though this prevents the build file from exiting when a compilation error occurs, it also appears to make the build file exit the  task. This is a problem because, unless the form that does not compile successfully is the last to be tested (based on the filename of the form in alphanumerical decsending order), there will be one or more forms that the build file does not attempt to compile. So, for example, if the folder containing the forms that are desired to be compiled contains 10 forms and the first form does not compile successfully, the build file will not attempt to compile the remaining 9 forms (ie exit the  task). Is there a way to make the build file attempt to compile remaining forms after encountering after failing to compile a form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this has now been solved. The problem is that the you need to set “failonerror” in the  task instead.